# In node.js why i'm not getting error while trying to write the non existing file

Tags: node.js, file

In the below code,i'm trying to write the non existing file 'doesnotexist.text' but still i'm getting the result as success.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('doesnotexist.text', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
if (err) {
   console.log('error is '+err);
   return;
 }
else{
  console.log('success.');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `writeFile` function creates the file if it does not exist.

Basically, you can change the behavior of this function by submitting an `options` object as third parameter, as described in the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback). For the `flags` property you can provide any value from the ones described in the documentation for [fs.open](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

For write, they are:

- `w` - Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).
- `wx` - Like `w` but opens the file in exclusive mode.
- `w+` - Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).
- `wx+` - Like `w+` but opens the file in exclusive mode.

The default value for `writeFile` is `w`, hence the file is created if it does not exist. As there is no option that provides an error when the file does not exist, you need an additional check whether the file already exists.

For this, check out the `fs.exists` function (see [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) for details).

Basically, your code should somewhat like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.exists('foo.txt', function (exists) {
  if (!exists) {
    return 'Error, file foo.txt does not exist!';
  }

  fs.writeFile('foo.txt', ...);
});
```

Comment: ok thank you.After seeing your answer i refreshed my project folder.yes it created the files which i tried to write.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could mark my answer as answer and up-vote it :-)